# Mongodb Aggregration merge not working with archived data restore

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm getting `Document does not contain key coll` when I try to restore data from the online archived database. I connected to the archive database and then ran the below query.

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id": 1,
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": {
        "atlas": {
          "projectId": "<project-id>",
          "clusterName": "<cluster-name>",
          "db": "<db>",
          "coll": "<collection>"
        }
      },
      "on": [ "internalId" ],
      "whenMatched": "keepExisting",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Did you confirm that **all** documents have a non-empty `internalId` field? The error message states that there is at least one without, and he docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#std-label-merge-on explicitly says that the key field must be a non-empty scalar.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes all of the archived data entries have an internal ID field. Still I'm getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this question by reaching out to the Mongo support team.
This Query throws errors only in

> Studio 3T

Mongo shell It is working fine in Mongo shell. I installed Mongo shell by following this documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/

Please Use Mongo shell to execute command if anyone face this kind of issues with 3rd party shells